# Segue "show detail" does not work in iOS 7 - Swift

Tags: swift, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, segue

My first screen is a navigation controller then comes my login view and if I log in and i see my Slide-out Sidebar Menu. I log in with iOS7 but backbutton is superimposed on menu-slide but i can see my menu-slide in iOS 8 and it does not appear the backbutton.
When I pass from login to Slide-out Sidebar Menu view, I use segue "show detail" not inherit the backbutton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use 'show' instead of show detail because show detail will create a modal like separate view.

In ios8 apple changed the way they handle view controller segue animations.

[Here is a chart](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_storyboard/chapters/StoryboardSegue.html)  on apples website that explains the different ones

Comment: But if I use "show" in iOS 7 and 8 appears backbutton and I don't see my menu-slide, how can i disable the backbutton? or that is not inherited to the next view. The link don't work.

Comment: i guess i'm confused about what your trying to do.  I thought you wanted the back button to show.  perhaps a pic of what your issue is might be helpful